Is there a name for this nice property of the usual weak incompressible Navier-Stokes equation?
Navier-Stokes is a non-linear PDE, and there is no standard, general theory of weak solutions for nonlinear PDEs.  But the literature on weak solutions to the incompressible Navier-Stokes constantly uses a specific weakening of the equation which has this nice property: any smooth function which is a weak solution (in the sense of this weak form) is in fact a strong solution.  This is much less informative than weak-strong uniqueness because it says nothing about uniqueness. But in return, it is trivial to prove.
My question is:  Is there a standard term for describing those weak forms of PDEs such that every weak solution which is also a smooth function is a strong solution?
In case that is unclear I will give more detail.  The unforced Navier Stokes equation is often expressed as
$$\partial_t \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{ u} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u} =  \nu\cdot\nabla^2 \mathbf{u} -\nabla p .$$
But when $\mathbf{u}$ is smooth, and we assume incompressibility, this is equivalent to 
$$\partial_t \mathbf{u} + \nabla (\mathbf{ u} \otimes \mathbf{u}) =  \nu\cdot\nabla^2 \mathbf{u} -\nabla p .$$
This latter equation is still nonlinear but it can be weakened by the same, standard procedure used to weaken linear PDEs.  Integrate it against any test function, using formal integration by parts to remove the derivatives from $\mathbf{u}$ and $\nabla (\mathbf{ u} \otimes \mathbf{u})$ and put them on the test function.  So any divergence free smooth function that solves all those integral equations, solves the original PDE.

A smooth function that satisfies the weak formulation is also a strong solution is called equivalent and a strong solution that satisfies the weak formulation is consistent.

@DanielCazares Thanks.  This should be posted as an answer.

The property that you describe is automatic in any reasonable situation. A more interesting phenomenon is "weak-strong uniqueness" which means that if a weak solution and strong solution agree at a single time, then they are equal for all time. This is false for general weak solutions of the Navier-Stokes but true for the class of Leray-Hopf solutions.

A smooth function that satisfies the weak formulation is also a strong solution is called equivalent and a strong solution that satisfies the weak formulation is consistent.

This terminology confuses me. Are you saying that a smooth function that satisfies a certain property is called "equivalent"? Equivalent to what?

It could be worded more clearly:  A weak formulation with the property that every smooth weak solution is a strong solution is called an equivalent weak formulation.  And a weak formulation with the property that every strong solution satisfies the weak formulation is called a consistent weak formulation.
